# Mining behind a proxy and restrictive firewall (only http ports allowed) - possible?

Tags: mining-pools, gpu-mining, miner-configuration, proxy, firewall

I have a very restrictive firewall with an additional proxy here. Is there a GPU mining tool out there that supports proxy server?
The best would be a SSL connection to the mining pool. A long living stream also doesn't work I think, because Internet radio is not possible.

I don't have a PC on the outside, so SSH tunnel is no option.

Edit:
Mining over a website could be a solution too. I tried http://www.bitcoinplus.com/ and it worked after setting the http proxy to a correct value for Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching and searching I found these possiblites.

- Use bitminter Java client in Version 1.1.2 http://bitminter.com/client/1.1.2/bitminter.jnlp (current version doesn't work)
- Make your own miner which supports proxy
- Use a tool like Proxifier (I have not tested it personally, because it is commercial)
- Use simpleproxy on a remote machine [simpleproxy man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/simpleproxy/)
- Use [stratumproxy.io](https://stratumproxy.io) (also supports SSL)

Answer (score 2):

Most mining software supports connecting to a pool through any port. It is up to your pool to provide mining capabilities through the appropriate ports. I personally faced a similar problem when developing a pool implementation on Google App Engine - I only had HTTP and HTTPS ports available, and mining through them wasn't a problem.

As I doubt any mining pool would change their protocol to allow mining through HTTP ports, you can use any virtual machine to forward you mining traffic through them. For example, [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) offers free virtual machine hosting for a year as far as I remember.

Comment: Amazon is only free for 750 **hours**. The main issue is to have a mining tool that supports a http proxy to connect through.

Comment: @otakun85 750 free hours per month equal to 31.25 free days per month, which should be enough for any month;). This way you could set up a SSH tunnel.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I should have read it more carefully. But either way it only works for the first sign up. So you have to cheat to sign up more than once.
I may have found a way to use guiminer behind proxy/firewall. I try it tomorrow.

Comment: poclbm seems to support http proxy (looking at the source). But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There are some pools which allow mining through port 80, e.g. port80.btcguild.com.

But I still search for a encrypted connection through HTTPS/ port 443. Anybody?

Comment: To have a pool with port 80/443 is one thing. The main problem is to find a miner, which allows to set a http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

use one of http proxies listed at http://www.publicproxyservers.com/proxy/list_uptime1.html

for example:

```
./minerd --algo scrypt --url stratum+tcp://pool-server:port \
--userpass user:pass\
-P \
-x orlaproxy.info
```